# How to support multiple users/multiple GitHub accounts with the IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: git, github, jetbrains-ide

I created 2 GitHub accounts. One personal and another corporate. After that, I began to lay out the code on my personal account, but the code began to be laid out on behalf of the corporate address on my personal git account. I use JetBrains' products.

How to fix it?

Screenshot of my repo:

[image]

I tried to look at the account in the version control, but nothing worked.

Comment: Are you using an ssh key or a username and password when you push to github?

Comment: I don't know, I think not

Answer (score 3):

> Are you using an ssh key or a username and password when you push to github

Whatever the protocol (SSH or HTTPS) you are using, what matter is your:

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

If you have done past commits with the wrong user.name/user.email, follow:

- "[Why are my commits linked to the wrong user?](https://help.github.com/en/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user)"
- "[Changing author info](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info)"
  And for your next commit, do set the right user name/email.

Those involve Git using command-line, but will then be picked up by the IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: Interesting. Didn’t know github would allow you to push a commit using another user’s email. This means you can basically impersonate another user in a commit if you have access to the same repository that they have.

Comment: @DelenaMalan GitHub only reflects the content of the Git repository, with its committer/author for each commit. And in a Git repository, you can commit as anyone you want, simply by settings those user.name/email configurations. Since it is a *decentralized* system, there is no local control of the identity used. You could sign your work however, if you want a stricter control: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work, https://dev.to/sdmg15/gpg-signing-your-git-commits-3epc

Comment: @DelenaMalan although... that (signing your commit) would depend on the integrity of a key server. Which, these days, is not always a given: https://twitter.com/FiloSottile/status/1145089715873488896

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @VonC's answer

**Change git user only for the project:**

```
git config user.name "John Doe"
git config user.email "John@doe.com"
```

It will only affect the current project and will change the `.git/config` directory under your repository.

**Change git user for the system user:**

If you want to apply it on all your repositories you need to add `--global` option on the command.

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email "John@doe.com"
```

This will change the `~/.gitconfig` under your home directory.

**Change git user for every user in system:**

If you have multiple users on the machine, and want to change this for all users you need to add `--system` option.

```
git config --system user.name "John Doe"
git config --system user.email "John@doe.com"
```

To verify your changes, use these commands

```
git config --get user.name
git config --get user.email
```